# Getting an IM Property from Contact

Tags: android, xmpp, android-contacts

I am writing a jabber messenger for android and would like to check the Phone Contact list for potential chat partners ;)

Cannot figure out how to get the specific property of the Contact. Getting DisplayName is not the Problem but getting IM UserNames.

Can somebody maybe just post a query and the code where the jabber UserName is extracted? I just don't get it

Thanks in advance
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) and [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.html), you will find everything you need.

Basically, you have to query the rows where `MIMETYPE = Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` and `DATA5 = PROTOCOL_JABBER`. The jabber username of this contact is stored in `DATA1`.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what i was asking for M.